# php explode and remove # and ,

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, explode

I have an array of colours stored which are presented like so. As you can see color_codes are stored with a hash and comma.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Black
                    [color_codes] => #000000,#000000,
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Red
                    [color_codes] => #FF0033,
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => White
                    [color_codes] => #FFFFFF,
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_color] => Black
                    [color_codes] => #0C0C0C,#0C0C0C,
                )

        )
)
```

Is it possible using explode to remove the # at the front of each color and replace the comma with a - (dash) symbol.

Would foreach through each item achieve this? i have tried removing the hash like so put i am having no luck.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($colours); $i++) {
    $colours[$i]['color_codes'] = str_replace('#', '', $colours[$i]['color_codes']);
}
```

What i am aiming for is the colors to look like this if there are two for example `FFFFFF-FFFFFF-`

Comment: Is the main array is $colours? then your for loop is wrong. $colours[$i]['color_codes'] is non existent.

Comment: Hi yes the main aray is $colours, Will i need to go one level deeper within the array then?

Comment: Yes. You can use @sergio answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, hope it will help

```
foreach($mainArray as $arrayM){

    foreach($arrayM as $subArray){
         $subArray['color_codes'] = str_replace('#', '',  $subArray['color_codes']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add closing parenthesis for outer foreach loop?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked perfectly. I just needed to foreach through again for the next array down. thanks again :) I will mark when i can